# SimpleSaml and WSO2 Identity Provider 5

Tags: wso2, simplesamlphp, wso2-identity-server

Perhaps someone can assist.

I've setup Simplesaml on a server and i am attempting to use it to auth off wso2 (which is using a facebook authenticator) and its running on a different server.

When i test the simplesaml i get the following error

```
SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION

Backtrace:
0 /var/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:180 (N/A)
Caused by: SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Could not find the metadata of an IdP with entity ID 'localhost'
Backtrace:
2 /var/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Auth/Source/SP.php:134 (sspmod_saml_Auth_Source_SP::getIdPMetadata)
1 /var/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php:74 (require)
0 /var/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:135 (N/A)
`
```

As you can see its complaining about localhost idp. I really cannot find any reference to localhost in any of my configurations files. Has anyone seen this before.

Thanks in advance for the assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in SAML Assertion that is sent by Identity Server, contains  `localhost` value. Could you please verify.  If you can edit this value using the management console of identity server.

You need to configure the issuer name in the Identity Server side. By default, it has been configured as `localhost`. You can login to management console of Identity Server and configure the `Resident Identity Provider` which can be seen under `Identity Provider -> List` menu.

I have attached a screen shot on configuring it. [image]